# Jquery Get ID and Search

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a Jquery Get Method here.  And in this method I reload the html page.  So in the function(data)  I get a blob of HTML.  Can you tell me how I can search it to find a control by its ID.  Its mainly used to replace the control.

this works on chrome but fails on ie

```
x = $("<div>").append(data).find("#ControlID").html();
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

I have attempted to just run x = $("").append(data).html() and even that returns blank.  I do have  tags on the page I am attempting to load?

Comment: Try this: x = $("<div></div>").append(data).find("#ControlID").html();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are trying to find the control inside the HTML returned by jQuery.get:

```
var theJqObjectFound = $(data).find('#your_id_here');
```

Answer (score 0):

Find element within response data:

```
var $control = $(data).find("#ControlID").html();
```

append it to `body`:

```
   $control.appendTo($('body'));
```

Comment: Ive tried this above but the problem is in Chrome it works fine and in IE 8 it returns "" or null

Comment: Make sure that the response `data` contains valid HTML. `$('<div id="ControlID"><p>This is the response.</p></div>').find("#ControlID").html();` should return "<p>This is the response.</p>"

Answer (score 0):

Try $("div") as your selector. jQuery selectors work like CSS selectors and dont need the tag code